# Final классы в C++

Tags: c++

Возможно ли в С++ определить класс как final в Java, т.е. неподлежащим дальнейшему расширению?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот еще нашел в гугле статью: [C++ без галстука (часть 1 : Final class )](http://www.kabit.ru/c/c-без-галстука-часть-1).

Comment: Спасибо. Блестящая статья.

Answer (score 5):

В стандарте С++11 есть спецификатор final, который можно применять как для классов так и для методов.
[Wiki: Explicit overrides and final](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final)

Comment: Да, но она еще в известных мне компиляторах не поддерживается. Хотя, думаю, ждать осталось немного.

Comment: В gcc-4.7 поддерживается.

Answer (score 1):

Способ есть, но это лишь нотация. Ей можно следовать, а можно и нет. Для объявления класса, от которого нельзя наследоваться, необходимо *не объявлять* его деструктор как `virtual`.

Comment: Это даже как нотация не работает, поскольку если в базовом классе объявлен виртуальный диструктор, а в его наследнике нет, то что же получается наследовать от наследника нельзя?

Comment: Место для виртуального деструктора в этой ситуации у производного класса всё равно будет в таблице виртуальных методов. Просто там будет указатель на деструктор базового класса.